# python turtle drawing is not visible, the window stays open but nothing appears on it

Tags: python-3.x, python-turtle

I am learning python, I have started on a simple pong game. I have the code to draw two paddles on both sides of the screen the paddles don't appear just a blank screen in the output. Here is the code:

> ```
> import turtle
>
> #creating a window for pong
> win = turtle.Screen()
> win.title("PONG")
> win.bgcolor("white")
> win.setup(width=800, height=600)
> win.tracer(0)
>
>
>
> #creating paddle A
> paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
> paddle_a.speed(0)
> paddle_a.color("black")
> paddle_a.shape("square")
> paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
> paddle_a.penup()
> paddle_a.goto(-350,0)
>
>
> #creating paddle B
> paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
> paddle_b.speed(0)
> paddle_b.color("black")
> paddle_b.shape("square")
> paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
> paddle_b.penup()
> paddle_b.goto(350,0)
>
>
> #ball
> ball = turtle.Turtle()
> ball.speed(0)
> ball.color("black")
> ball.shape("square")
> ball.penup()
> ball.goto(0,0)
>
> win.exitonclick()
> ```

PLEASE TELL ME WHERE I AM WRONG!!

Comment: Please update your question with information about where you are attempting to learn python. Do you have your development environment set up correctly? Trying making the program shorter and incrementally add code until you see the problem again. These are a few techniques to try. Please add the details of these results to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `win.tracer(0)`, the drawn shapes appear. It's unintelligible what you want to achieve with `tracer(0)`, since according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer) this means *only each* zero*th regular screen update is really performed*, which is nonsense per se.